# How do I extract the first word from a list of words?

Tags: r, text-mining

I'm having trouble extracting the first word from a list of words. I've tried substring, gsub, and str_extract but still haven't figured it out. Please advise. Thank you. Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
Word
"c("print", "printing", "prints")"
"c("take", "takes", "taking")"
"c("score", "scoring", "scored")"
```

I'm trying to extract the first word from the list that looks like this:

```
Extracted
print
take
score
```

Comment: Is Word the column of a dataframe? and each vector refers to a list?

Comment: Are you showing us literal text, a list of text vectors, or something else?

Comment: yes, Word is the name of the column. I converted it into a data frame.

Comment: Please share a `dput()` of your data so it's clear exactly what your input is. What you've shared now is not valid R input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using base R alone

```
##Just to recreate the data
df <- tibble(
  Word= list(c("print", "printing", "prints"),c("take", "takes", "taking"),c("score", "scoring", "scored")))

###
df$Extracted <- sapply(1:length(df$Word), function(i)df$Word[[i]][1])
```

Comment: Thank you. I have a much longer list of words but this approach actually solved the issue I was facing.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `purrr::map` with an index argument as follows:

If you want your output returned as a list:

```
  > purrr::map(Word, 1)
  # [[1]]
  # [1] "print"
  #
  # [[2]]
  # [1] "take"
  #
  # [[3]]
  # [1] "score"
```

If you want it returned as a vector:

```
  > purrr::map_chr(Word, 1)
  # [1] "print" "take"  "score"
```